# Face detection sample of opencv

Tags: android, windows, opencv

When i run application on device app crashes with below massage-

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load detection_based_tracker:
>   findLibrary returned null

I am using OpenCV-2.4.4-beta-android-sdk and running on android 2.3.6

Please help!!

Comment: No i was thanking you for response... :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have solved problem y changing two things:

1) Right click on project-> property ->c/c++ build in builder setting field give manually full path of your ndk then apply and ok

2) In jni/application.mk do APP_ABI := armeabi

:)

Comment: do not forget to accept your answer after 8hours so it could help others later !