# Android OpenCV - Couldn't load detection_based_tracker

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

I am trying to build a face detection android application using OpenCV 3.0.0.I am following the sample provided along with opencv. I am using android-studio and have done a static initialization of opencv. The initialization work fine.

But the`System.loadLibrary("detection_based_tracker");` fails with the following error "**Couldn't load detection_based_tracker from loader : findLibrary returned null** "

I did search this issue and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14973151/face-detection-sample-of-opencv) link. I have installed the NDK and assigned the path. But I am not able to find the "**jni/application.mk**" file.

Can you please help me resolve this error.

Comment: `jni/application.mk` file is not obligatory, if you don't have one, then create it. It should be in same folder as `Android.mk`

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to modify the Android.mk file, Ex.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

#OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=off
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
#OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED

include /home/cobalt/Android/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := DetectionBasedTracker_jni.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_LDLIBS     += -llog -ldl

LOCAL_MODULE     := detection_based_tracker

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Note: Change 'include /home/cobalt/Android/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk' to your own OpenCV-android-sdk path!

Here are the sample projects in OpenCV 3.0 Face Detection (imported in Android Studio).

1. Manual compile with ndk-build:

   - OpenCV 3.0 Face Detection Sample (https://github.com/DeLaSalleUniversity-Manila/opencvfacedetection-melvincabatuan)
2. Using the Experimental Gradle plugin:

   - Face Detection in OpenCV with Gradle Experimental Plugin (https://github.com/DeLaSalleUniversity-Manila/facedetectionopencvwithgradleexperimentalplugin-melvincabatuan)

Hopefully this helps.